# Why does adding custom fonts to my application's plist prevent the storyboard's initial scene from loading?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have an app with a `main.storyboard` with a scene correctly set as the initial view controller. When I start the app and run it, this scene comes up as expected.

My problem occurs when I attempt to add custom fonts to the project. When I edit my `info.plist` to include the fonts in the `Fonts provided by application` section and then attempt to run the app, it remains stuck on the launch screen and the initial scene from the storyboard is never loaded. If I then remove the `Fonts provided ...` section from my `info.plist` file and run it again, the initial screen loads up as expected.

What am I doing wrong here? Does it matter where in the plist the entry is (like at the top or at the bottom)?

Answer (score 1):

So, I discovered that my code was hanging/freezing completely when attempting to call `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` (which is a necessary part of registering custom fonts). This was being called before anything else was loaded, so the freezing on this call was preventing the main screen from ever appearing.

The "fix" (gleaned from nearly-unrelated posts) was to add this line prior to the call(s) to `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider`:

```
UIFont.familyNames() // you don't need to iterate this array or do anything with it
```

No more hanging, app starts up as before and custom fonts all work properly.